# Using sockets in android?

Tags: android, sockets, pusher

What I am asking is a way or advice how to reimplement my app that receives data from sockets.  My app now connects to pusher service and gets the data from the socket. When new event (new data on pusher) is received the data is updated to the UI and thread for receiving data waits for a new event.

This works ok, as long as internet is available. When internet drops, sockets are not reestablished.

I have an android service in which I receive data and then publish the result to the subscribers. Subscribers then call the UI update method with data and after that android service for receiving data is called again.

However android service is first called on onResume activity and in subscriber after every successful data. However if the network drops the service is not started again. How should I handle this?

My first idea was when the network drops I started activity that checks network availability every 2 seconds and if network becomes available it restarts the sockets. However it does not work as reliable as I want.

If you need to see the code I will post it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to listen for [CONNECTIVITY_ACTION](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager.html#CONNECTIVITY_ACTION).The docs says:

> A change in network connectivity has occurred. A connection has either
>   been established or lost. The NetworkInfo for the affected network is
>   sent as an extra; it should be consulted to see what kind of
>   connectivity event occurred.
>
> If this is a connection that was the result of failing over from a
>   disconnected network, then the FAILOVER_CONNECTION boolean extra is
>   set to true.
>
> For a loss of connectivity, if the connectivity manager is attempting
>   to connect (or has already connected) to another network, the
>   NetworkInfo for the new network is also passed as an extra. This lets
>   any receivers of the broadcast know that they should not necessarily
>   tell the user that no data traffic will be possible. Instead, the
>   receiver should expect another broadcast soon, indicating either that
>   the failover attempt succeeded (and so there is still overall data
>   connectivity), or that the failover attempt failed, meaning that all
>   connectivity has been lost.
>
> For a disconnect event, the boolean extra EXTRA_NO_CONNECTIVITY is set
>   to true if there are no connected networks at all.
>
> Constant Value: "android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE"

Refer the following code snippet from [here](http://www.netmite.com/android/mydroid/frameworks/base/core/java/android/net/NetworkConnectivityListener.java)

```
/*
 * Copyright (C) 2006 The Android Open Source Project
 *
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 * you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 * You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 *      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 * limitations under the License.
 */

package android.net;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Message;
import android.util.Log;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Iterator;

/**
 * A wrapper for a broadcast receiver that provides network connectivity
 * state information, independent of network type (mobile, Wi-Fi, etc.).
 * {@hide}
 */
public class NetworkConnectivityListener {
    private static final String TAG = "NetworkConnectivityListener";
    private static final boolean DBG = false;

    private Context mContext;
    private HashMap<Handler, Integer> mHandlers = new HashMap<Handler, Integer>();
    private State mState;
    private boolean mListening;
    private String mReason;
    private boolean mIsFailover;

    /** Network connectivity information */
    private NetworkInfo mNetworkInfo;

    /**
     * In case of a Disconnect, the connectivity manager may have
     * already established, or may be attempting to establish, connectivity
     * with another network. If so, {@code mOtherNetworkInfo} will be non-null.
     */
    private NetworkInfo mOtherNetworkInfo;

    private ConnectivityBroadcastReceiver mReceiver;

    private class ConnectivityBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            String action = intent.getAction();

            if (!action.equals(ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION) ||
                mListening == false) {
                Log.w(TAG, "onReceived() called with " + mState.toString() + " and " + intent);
                return;
            }

            boolean noConnectivity =
                intent.getBooleanExtra(ConnectivityManager.EXTRA_NO_CONNECTIVITY, false);

            if (noConnectivity) {
                mState = State.NOT_CONNECTED;
            } else {
                mState = State.CONNECTED;
            }

            mNetworkInfo = (NetworkInfo)
                intent.getParcelableExtra(ConnectivityManager.EXTRA_NETWORK_INFO);
            mOtherNetworkInfo = (NetworkInfo)
                intent.getParcelableExtra(ConnectivityManager.EXTRA_OTHER_NETWORK_INFO);

            mReason = intent.getStringExtra(ConnectivityManager.EXTRA_REASON);
            mIsFailover =
                intent.getBooleanExtra(ConnectivityManager.EXTRA_IS_FAILOVER, false);

            if (DBG) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onReceive(): mNetworkInfo=" + mNetworkInfo +  " mOtherNetworkInfo = "
                        + (mOtherNetworkInfo == null ? "[none]" : mOtherNetworkInfo +
                        " noConn=" + noConnectivity) + " mState=" + mState.toString());
            }

            // Notifiy any handlers.
            Iterator<Handler> it = mHandlers.keySet().iterator();
            while (it.hasNext()) {
                Handler target = it.next();
                Message message = Message.obtain(target, mHandlers.get(target));
                target.sendMessage(message);
            }
        }
    };

    public enum State {
        UNKNOWN,

        /** This state is returned if there is connectivity to any network **/
        CONNECTED,
        /**
         * This state is returned if there is no connectivity to any network. This is set
         * to true under two circumstances:
         * <ul>
         * <li>When connectivity is lost to one network, and there is no other available
         * network to attempt to switch to.</li>
         * <li>When connectivity is lost to one network, and the attempt to switch to
         * another network fails.</li>
         */
        NOT_CONNECTED
    }

    /**
     * Create a new NetworkConnectivityListener.
     */
    public NetworkConnectivityListener() {
        mState = State.UNKNOWN;
        mReceiver = new ConnectivityBroadcastReceiver();
    }

    /**
     * This method starts listening for network connectivity state changes.
     * @param context
     */
    public synchronized void startListening(Context context) {
        if (!mListening) {
            mContext = context;

            IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
            filter.addAction(ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION);
            context.registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter);
            mListening = true;
        }
    }

    /**
     * This method stops this class from listening for network changes.
     */
    public synchronized void stopListening() {
        if (mListening) {
            mContext.unregisterReceiver(mReceiver);
            mContext = null;
            mNetworkInfo = null;
            mOtherNetworkInfo = null;
            mIsFailover = false;
            mReason = null;
            mListening = false;
        }
    }

    /**
     * This methods registers a Handler to be called back onto with the specified what code when
     * the network connectivity state changes.
     *
     * @param target The target handler.
     * @param what The what code to be used when posting a message to the handler.
     */
    public void registerHandler(Handler target, int what) {
        mHandlers.put(target, what);
    }

    /**
     * This methods unregisters the specified Handler.
     * @param target
     */
    public void unregisterHandler(Handler target) {
        mHandlers.remove(target);
    }

    public State getState() {
        return mState;
    }

    /**
     * Return the NetworkInfo associated with the most recent connectivity event.
     * @return {@code NetworkInfo} for the network that had the most recent connectivity event.
     */
    public NetworkInfo getNetworkInfo() {
        return mNetworkInfo;
    }

    /**
     * If the most recent connectivity event was a DISCONNECT, return
     * any information supplied in the broadcast about an alternate
     * network that might be available. If this returns a non-null
     * value, then another broadcast should follow shortly indicating
     * whether connection to the other network succeeded.
     *
     * @return NetworkInfo
     */
    public NetworkInfo getOtherNetworkInfo() {
        return mOtherNetworkInfo;
    }

    /**
     * Returns true if the most recent event was for an attempt to switch over to
     * a new network following loss of connectivity on another network.
     * @return {@code true} if this was a failover attempt, {@code false} otherwise.
     */
    public boolean isFailover() {
        return mIsFailover;
    }

    /**
     * An optional reason for the connectivity state change may have been supplied.
     * This returns it.
     * @return the reason for the state change, if available, or {@code null}
     * otherwise.
     */
    public String getReason() {
        return mReason;
    }
}

syntax highlighted by Code2HTML, v. 0.9.1
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what @rupesh jain suggested. you should use `BroadcastReceiver` to monitor the network status, and take appropriate actions when the connectivity is established (reconnect sockets) or lost (disconnect socket and maybe save the state of the last requests).